# What’s the significance of the rain on the second night at Freddy's?

Tags: analysis, effects, five-nights-at-freddys

In *Five Nights at Freddy’s* (2023), on the second night that Mike Schmidt works as a security guard at the abandoned Freddy Fazbear’s Pizza Place, it rains.

Just like the previous night, Mike falls asleep.  Shortly after waking up (as a character in his dream attacks him) there is a buzz on the doorbell.  Mike then lets police officer Vanessa Shelly into the building before she proceeds to give him a tour of the pizzeria.

[image: Vanessa (wearing a poncho) being let into Freddy Fazbear’s by Mike]

At the end of Mike’s shift (in the morning) it has stopped raining but there are still puddles in the carpark.

**Does the rain mean anything to the story or is it merely happenstance?**

---

It isn’t trivial to incorporate weather into the filming of a scene, so when it rains it usually signifies *something* (be it sadness, turmoil, renewal, etc.) or it’s an excuse for the characters to stay indoors.  But this doesn’t really track with (what I can remember of) the rest of the movie.

It does rain in one or two particularly important scenes in the related video game series, but these scenes don’t seem to line up with anything in the film.

Comment: Likely it was just raining when they filmed it.